# Getting the width of an Object and offseting not working

Tags: javascript

So I'm attempting to set up a rotating banner on my website (viewable at https://www.leapcraft.net) and I have a variable that gets the width of the element and should be offsetting the element not inside of the div by the number of pixels.

I've tried setting the values back to their original offset which fixes it.

```
var bannerStatus = 1;
var bannerTimer = 4000;
var element = document.getElementById("main-banner");
var positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var o = positionInfo.width;

window.onload = function() {
   bannerLoop();
}

var startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
   bannerLoop();
}, bannerTimer);

function bannerLoop() {
   if (bannerStatus === 1) {
      document.getElementById("imgban2").style.opacity = "0";

      setTimeout(function() {

      document.getElementById("imgban1").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("imgban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("imgban2").style.right = "-"+ o;
      document.getElementById("imgban2").style.zIndex = "1500";
      document.getElementById("imgban3").style.right = o;
      document.getElementById("imgban3").style.zIndex = "500";
   }, 500);
   setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("imgban2").style.opacity = "1";
   }, 1000);
      bannerStatus = 2;
   }
```

Expected Results: Rotating banner that is responsive to Width of device that is defined in style.css

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use css styles to rotate image? Look on my solution, maybe will be useful to you.

```
function bannerLoop() { 
  imgBanner[imgNum].style.opacity=1;
  imgBanner[imgNum].style.WebkitTransitionDuration='';
  imgBanner[imgNum].style.webkitTransform = '';  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    imgBanner[imgNum].style.WebkitTransitionDuration='1s';
    imgBanner[imgNum].style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(360deg)';     
    imgBanner[imgNum].style.opacity=0;

    (imgNum<imgBanner.length-1)?imgNum++:imgNum=0
  },3000)
}
```

And here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udtr659y/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake by rotating i mean like an image slideshow where the image slides out then loops